# Split an email address into username, host and domain

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade, email-address

I get an email address from the database. I need to split and collect it to protect it. There is a way, but I don't understand how to apply it fully.

For example we have an email address `me@example.com`

We split it down:

```
> me
> example
> com
```

and collect.

Here is an example function

```
@php

$split = explode('@', $email);
$first = $split[0];
$second = explode('.', $split[1])[0];
$third = explode('.', $split[1])[1];

<a href="" data-first="first" data-second="second" data-third="third">{{ $email }}</a>

@endphp
```

How can I properly apply the fields `$first` `$second` `$third` to collect the email?

Comment: When you say "apply", do you mean how to put those values into the `data-` attributes of the HTML? It's not very clear what exactly your issue is. Try to be very specific about the goal and the problem instead of using ambiguous words. Thanks,.

Comment: @ADyson yes, that's right, sorry if something is not clear

Comment: What you really want is so unclear. Please tell us what you really want.

Comment: @Ajay i need to put values `$first` `$second` `$third` ​​in `data-`attributes

Comment: Would you like to get an email from the user by this email? If it is, you don't need to split it just use simple HTML `<a href="mailto:{{$email}}>{{$email}}</a>`

Comment: Ok and what is stopping you from doing that exactly? Did you try anything? You clearly know how to use blade syntax because you wrote `{{ $email }}` already. So why can't you write `data-first="{{ $first }}"` etc in the same way?

Comment: @MainulHasan I need this way to protect against spam, but I also need to receive messages on it

Comment: @ADyson okay, thanks

Comment: @MainulHasan Maybe then tell me which method is better to use for protection in my case

Comment: P.S. I also don't think this technique will be that helpful against spam, because if someone scrapes your page for email addresses, their bot will still see the email address in full where you've put `{{ $email }}`. So they can still harvest it and send spam to it.

Comment: @ADyson Is there some good way for my case?

Comment: It's not something I have personal expertise in so I can't tell you what the latest techniques are myself, but I would expect if you [do some research, starting by clicking on this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=protect+mailto+links+from+spam) then you'll get more than enough information to help you - one thing I do know is that this is not a new problem.

Comment: @ADyson I'm understood, thank you

Answer (score 0):

why not do it in simple way?

just echo it with php code will do.

```
$split = explode('@', $email);
$first = $split[0];
$second = explode('.', $split[1])[0];
$third = explode('.', $split[1])[1];

<a href="" data-first="<?=$first?>" data-second="<?=$second?>" data-third="<?=$third?>">{{ $email }}</a>
```

Comment: You can see from the original that OP is using Laravel blade syntax though...it would make sense to stick to that format, for consistency and reliability.